# Laravel horizon remains inactive after a new deploy

Tags: laravel, redis, horizon

We have Horizon running for quite some time now, and have no issues with it.
But after our most recent deploy on production, it remains inactive and there are no workers being started.

I fail to see the problem, nor do we get any errors logged into bugsnag, so I'm a bit lost here.

What would be the best way to debug issues with Horizon?  I have verified, and I can talk to redis.  The dashboard also displays jobs on the queue, so it's just a matter of the workers not being started.

We're setting up our instances using Laravel forge, and I can confirm that there is a daemon that runs php artisan horizon in the correct directory.  Running that command manually on the server also doesn't give me much info that I can work with.

I'm sure here must be SOME error, but it's not beig caught / displayed / whatever.  Any thoughts on how to properly debug this?

This is the contents of config/horizon.php:

```php
<?php

return [
    'use' => 'default',
    'waits' => [
        'redis:default' => 60,
    ],
    'environments' => [
        'dev' => [
            'all-prio' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => ['default', 'high', 'medium', 'low'],
                'balance' => 'auto',
                'processes' => 10,
                'tries' => 3,
            ],
        ],
        'acc' => [
            'all-prio' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => ['default', 'high', 'medium', 'low'],
                'balance' => 'auto',
                'processes' => 10,
                'tries' => 3,
            ],
        ],
        'production' => [
            'high-prio' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => ['high'],
                'balance' => 'auto',
                'processes' => 10,
                'tries' => 5,
            ],
            'default-prio' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => ['medium', 'default'],
                'balance' => 'auto',
                'processes' => 10,
                'tries' => 3,
            ],
            'low-prio' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => ['low'],
                'balance' => 'auto',
                'processes' => 5,
                'tries' => 3,
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

The environment is correctly being set to 'production' on that environment.

This is the contents of the config/database.php redis section:

```php
    'redis' => [
        'cluster' => false,
        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ]
```

Comment: can you put horizon config in config folder?

Comment: It is definitely in the config folder - I'll paste the comments in the initial question as well...

Comment: question updated with the contents.

Comment: Can you also put your `redis` settings of the `database.php` file? And make sure that you don't have a `'persistent' => true` inside the redis database settings.

Comment: Hi - just added it to the initial question.  Just so you know: it has always been working - nothing has changed in config, but for some reason we now have an error which goes uncaught.   I'm more looking for a way to know how I can debug this...

Comment: @DavidHeremans any updates on it? Just got the same thing

Comment: `php artisan horizon` should start the `horizon`. I think you changed the code code somewhere and you can't remember where was it...